# Поменять шрифт только выделенной части текста в textbox C#, Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня реализован простейший блокнот. В нём можно поменять шрифт текста. Проблема в том, что если изменить шрифт текста, то он меняет шрифт всего текста, который есть в нашем textbox, а я хочу, что б если пользователь выделил какую-то часть, то шрифт поменялся только у выделенного текста, как в том же ворде. 
Главный textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Text" Width="773" Margin="0,13.4,0,10" FontSize="14" >
    </TextBox>
```

Combobox, отвечающий за выбор шрифта:

```
 <Label>Размер шрифта:</Label>
                <ComboBox x:Name="Select_Fontsize" SelectionChanged="Select_Fontsize_SelectionChanged">
                    <ComboBoxItem>10</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>12</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected ="True">14</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>16</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>18</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>20</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>22</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>24</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>30</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>42</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>64</ComboBoxItem>

                </ComboBox>
```

Код функции "Select_Fontsize_SelectionChanged":

```
  private void Select_Fontsize_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string FontSize = Select_Fontsize.SelectedItem.ToString();
        FontSize = FontSize.Substring(FontSize.Length - 2);
        if (Text != null)
        {
           string dt = Text.SelectedText;  //Тут я могу взять часть выделенного текста , но поменять его шрифт не получается т.к такое свойство есть только у textbox 
        }
            switch (FontSize) //то, как я меняю шрифт всего текста
        {
            case "10":
                Text.FontSize = 10;
                break;
                 case "12":
                Text.FontSize = 12;
                break;
                case "14":
                Text.FontSize = 14;
                break;
                case "16":
                Text.FontSize = 16;
                break;
                case "18":
                Text.FontSize = 18;
                break;
                case "20":
                Text.FontSize = 20;
                break;
            case "22":
                Text.FontSize = 22;
                break; case "24":
                Text.FontSize = 24;
                break;case "30":
                Text.FontSize = 30;
                break;case "42":
                Text.FontSize = 42;
                break;case "64":
                Text.FontSize = 64;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBox` так не умеет. Вам нужен [`RichTextBox`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox?view=netframework-4.8) и его свойство [`Selection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.selection?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_RichTextBox_Selection).

```csharp
TextSelection text = richTextBox.Selection; 
if (!text.IsEmpty) 
{ 
    text.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, FontSize); 
}
```

Вот еще [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview) и [примеры](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496865/wpf-richtextbox-how-to-change-selected-text-font)

Еще вам стоит весь блок `switch (FontSize) { ... }` заменить вот этой одной строчкой

```csharp
Text.FontSize = double.TryParse(FontSize, out double size) ? size : 12;
// где 12 - значение по умолчанию, если FontSize содержит невалидное значение
```